# Sort solr search result by a fixed order?

Tags: sorting, search, solr

There are 10 million items indexed in the solr system.
Each of them have field name `cid (collection ID)`

Eg.  cid=100   cid=101  cid=102 …
Totally about 50 collections

I want the search result sorted by fixed position of cid  (100, 101, 102)

Eg:

```
Item1 (cid=100)
Item2 (cid=101)
Item3 (cid=102)
Item4 (cid=100)
Item5 (cid=101)
Item6 (cid=102)
…
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean  by `fixed position of cid`?

Comment: ok, let me give an example. I want the search result sorted by cid sequence.   result item looping by a fixed order of cid, eg   cid=100  101  102          that mean the first item's cid should be 100, the second item's cid should be 101, the 3rd item's cid should be 102  and so on.

Comment: If the result contains multiple `cid=100` result, then will be coming together, followed by `cid=101. Am I right.

Comment: no.  lets say the result contains 5 results,  3 for cid100 2 for cid101. I expecting the outcome should be  cid100  cid101 cid100 cid101 cid100

Comment: I am not sure that can be achieved with default solr functionality.

Comment: You may have to do this manually. Solr can sort it (the regular way... 100,100,100,101,101...), and when you receive it form your application, work on it to re-sort it as you wish...

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I think it's not possible to do this manually.  for example - the search request limit 100 result then all of the 100 results are cid=100,   no chance for cid101 to popup on the top of result.  so i can not sort them manually.  seems no way to do it?   ?

Answer (score -1):

if cid is Integer type , you can sort field cid use asc rule!